# Laravel project not showing any page

Tags: php, windows, laravel, hosting

I prepared a Laravel 5.6 website (simple website, no database) on my local machine and it runs perfectly. Now that I want to deploy it in production I have a problem I cannot solve....

I followed a deployment path (copy from local public to public folder on the server and the other stuff to a separate folder that resides next to the public folder. All access rights are set according to the Laravel instruction, also adjusted the index.php.

But, despite all activities to find out the reason, the starting page never shows up. I added some additional debug statements to my index.php, and that indicates that this statement is not responding:

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
```

I am afraid that there is something wrong with the environment, so therefore I add the htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# SetEnv mod_developer secure-key-xxxxxxxxxxx
```

And also a relevant part of the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ASPClassic (*.htr)" path="*.htr" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="" />
        <add name="ASPClassic (*.cdx)" path="*.cdx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="" />
        <add name="ASPClassic (*.asa)" path="*.asa" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="" />
        <add name="php-7.2.3" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="" />
        <add name="PHP_via_FastCGI2" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="" />
        <add name="PHP_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="" />
        <add name="PHP_via_FastCGI1" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.0\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="" />
       <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" preCondition="" />
    </handlers>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="Default.html" />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="Default.aspx" />
            <add value="index.html" />
            <add value="index.php" />
            <add value="index.asp" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Auto" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In the webserver log I see following result:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-04-04 08:48:30
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
2018-04-04 08:48:30 W3SVC168 192.168.0.97 GET / - 443 - 94.208.181.162 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:59.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/59.0 - 200 0 0 31898 428 4715
2018-04-04 08:50:56 W3SVC168 192.168.0.97 GET / - 443 - 94.208.181.162 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:59.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/59.0 - 200 0 0 31914 454 702
2018-04-04 08:51:03 W3SVC168 192.168.0.97 GET / - 443 - 94.208.181.162 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:59.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/59.0 - 200 0 0 31914 454 561
2018-04-04 08:52:53 W3SVC168 192.168.0.97 GET / - 443 - 94.208.181.162 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:59.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/59.0 - 500 0 0 373 454 405
```

In this log I see an http-error 500, but what causes this error. ?I assume it is the main reason why my page does not show up.
So I hope someone can help me with this...

If you want to see the real world: [staging.rt-eureka.nl](http://staging.rt-eureka.nl)

Comment: Did you point the webserver to the /public folder?

Comment: Yes, in my opinion it does, because I added some echo's and var_dump's to the index.php and that works fine! At least until a certain point

Comment: did you set the proper permission of `/storage` and `/bootstrap/cache` folders?

Comment: I finally got it to work .....

Comment: I was not aware I had to change the URL inside some files (.env and app.php) and was not aware that I had to remove the cached config from bootstrap/cache/config.php. Also weird that the server did not give any response! At the moment I dropped the same stuf in the same manner at another domain, errror messages showed up and I was able to solve quite easily. Thanks all for your support